# Adding PHP/HTML code inside page from custom template

Tags: shortcode, page-template, child-theme

I'm helping my son with his financial site with some custom programming.  The first project for him is a custom spreadsheet using jQuery, flot, php, etc.

I created a child theme, created a template, functions.php, style sheet, etc, which all works well - as long as the spreadsheet is at the end of the page.  But now I'm trying to improve it by adding the ability for him to add text both before and after the spreadsheet.

My first idea was that I might be able to simply use a shortcode, but I don't know if that's the correct way.  It seems that shortcodes are not for outputting large amounts of mixed php/html. I can include the file and call a function in the spreadsheet file, and that works, but the shortcode so far hasn't done anything except print out the actual shortcode itself. But if it's an incorrect method, I don't want to waste time trying to make it work.

Any ideas for how I can do this?  I suppose I could just manually parse the_post() and process a shortcode myself, but I'd hate to do that if there's a method I can use that's built in.

**More Info**
I tried experimenting with shortcodes.  In my functions.php (which I know is being used because I load some javascript and css files):

```
function register_shortcodes() {
  add_shortcode('spreadsheet_placeholder', 'display_spreadsheet');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

I put a tag [spreadsheet_placeholder] in the middle of a page, and the page rendered with that tag in the middle.  Up until today, it just displayed the tag, but just now I got the bright idea to include the external php file containing the function (display_spreadsheet).

I got the spreadsheet to display after including the php file, just not the way I wanted.  But it did work.  It just displayed above the content rather than in the middle.  I had read that I need to return the data, not just ouput it directly, so I expected something like that.

I had tried using a nowdoc variable to save the entire function to a variable, but I think this is overly optimistic (maybe very much so), as I have mixed php and html with php tags, so I guess I would need to go into the php code and save it as several variables and concatenate them together to return the entire code.  But that's more of a php problem than WordPress, I guess.

At this point, I'm not sure which is easier - doing that, or parsing for a shortcode-like tag myself in the content of the page, and doing the logic in the code.

**The solution**

Thanks to bonger and Brad Dalton for the help with using ob_start(), something I've never used before.

I took my original php/html code out of it's file, and put it into a separate file, inside a function.  I included that file in functions.php, and pointed the shortcode registration to the function.  Then, using Brad's example, I returned the entire file at the end and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks to both of you.  I'm happy with the results, and so is my son.

Comment: Shortcodes can output as much stuff as you want, and would seem to be the way to go in your case - you're doing the `add_shortcode()` in your `init` action?

Comment: @bonger:  Thanks for the encouragement and tip.  I added extra information to my post with what I've done since the post; I've actually made a lot of progress by a simple addition of an include directive in functions.php.

Comment: You can wrap your included file in `ob_start()` and `$ret = ob_get_clean()` to gather all its echoed output into a string...

Comment: @bonger: Thanks, I've seen that, but never investigated.  Perhaps I should.  I was considering adding a the_post action in functions.php to just modify the post looking for the tag. But it could be more problematic than I think, so I'll check your suggestion. But will it work if I have embedded php and html mixed?

Comment: Yes, the embedded php will just be parsed as php by php as normal, so will just return html... I'd definitely go this (shortcode) way rather than doing your own parsing...

Comment: @bonger:  Thanks, I found an example similar to what I'm doing, and I think it will work. I think it may have been fairly easy to parse it, using a php parse function, but I was worried it might mess up with formatting.  Shortcodes do seem more flexible.

Comment: @bonger: I got it to work correctly using your suggestion. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept the answer and try to somehow document how I got it to work.  Otherwise, I'll answer it myself.

Comment: Good stuff! I see @Brad Dalton's just added an answer but if you add one too it could be useful to others...

Comment: Thats right and don't forget to click the arrow if you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to code the [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

And to execute a function using output buffering

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_tag', 'function_name' );
function function_name($atts) {
    ob_start();

    // Add your code

    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example for ob_start.  I used that exact example, and it worked well.  Since nobody else seemed to add an answer, I guess you get the acceptance credit. :-)